# onKeyDown event not firing

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, textfield

I made a form that contains a checkbox and a small input field. I have made a script to do two things:

- If the checkbox is checked, and there is no value inside the textbox, insert the name of the checkbox into the associated text field.
- If the user types into the textbox and the checkbox for the respective checkbox is not checked, check it.
- If the user clears out the textbox, pressing delete/backspace/etc, clear the check from the checkbox.

What is NOT working:
    * When a user types into the text field, the checkbox doesn't immediately (normally 2 keys are typed separately ) appear even though the logic says that when invokes, if the checkbox is unchecked, check it.
    * When a user clears the text area, using backspace/delete/etc., the checkbox remains.

What is working:

- A user clicks on the checkbox to auto-insert the checkbox value into the field. The user clicks on the checkbox again to clear the value from the textfield.

**[Here is the related coding being run on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/retched/X6Cnz/)**

```
function autocheck(ElementName, SectionName) {
//window.alert('keyword-' + SectionName + '-' + ElementName.toLowerCase());
    if (document.getElementById('keyword-' + SectionName + '-' + ElementName.toLowerCase()).checked == false)
    {
        document.getElementById('keyword-' + SectionName + '-' + ElementName.toLowerCase()).checked = true
    } 

    if (document.getElementById('keyword-' + SectionName + '-entry-' + ElementName.toLowerCase()).value == '')
    {
        document.getElementById('keyword-' + SectionName + '-' + ElementName.toLowerCase()).checked = false;
    }
}

function autofill(ElementName, SectionName) {
    ElementName=ElementName.replace(" ", "-"); 
    //window.alert('You got this: ' + ElementName);

    if(document.getElementById('keyword-' + SectionName + '-' + ElementName.toLowerCase()).checked == true)
    {
        document.getElementById('keyword-' + SectionName + '-entry-' + ElementName.toLowerCase()).value = document.getElementById('keyword-' + SectionName + '-' + ElementName.toLowerCase()).value;
    } else {
        document.getElementById('keyword-' + SectionName + '-entry-' + ElementName.toLowerCase()).value = '';
    }
}
```

And here is the related HTML

```
    <input type="checkbox" name="ufs_split_keywords[]" value="Throw" id="keyword-split-throw" onclick="autofill(this.value, 'split');"> <label for="keyword-split-throw">Throw</label>
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="ufs_split_keywords_entry[]" id="keyword-split-entry-throw" style="width:100px; float: right;" onkeydown="autocheck('throw', 'split');">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Use onkeyup instead of onkeydown!**

*Since you will only then get the changed value of the field.* 
At the timepoint of keydown-event the value of the input will be the old one / unchanged.

Keep the basic lifecyle of keypress on inputs in mind:

1. keydown-event bubbling
2. applying keyevent on input (mostly writing in it or deleting from it) 
    
   *can also be applied multiple times when the user holds the key*
3. keyup-event bubbling

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X6Cnz/1/) works for me perfectly. (Your code with only *onkeydown* changed to *onkeyup*)

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
              <script type="text/javascript">
                        function autocheck(ElementName, SectionName) {
                    //window.alert('keyword-' + SectionName + '-' + ElementName.toLowerCase());
                        if (document.getElementById('keyword-' + SectionName + '-' + ElementName.toLowerCase()).checked == false)
                        {
                            document.getElementById('keyword-' + SectionName + '-' + ElementName.toLowerCase()).checked = true
                        } 

                        if (document.getElementById('keyword-' + SectionName + '-entry-' + ElementName.toLowerCase()).value == '')
                        {
                            document.getElementById('keyword-' + SectionName + '-' + ElementName.toLowerCase()).checked = false;
                        }
                    }

                    function autofill(ElementName, SectionName) {
                        ElementName=ElementName.replace(" ", "-"); 
                        //window.alert('You got this: ' + ElementName);

                        if(document.getElementById('keyword-' + SectionName + '-' + ElementName.toLowerCase()).checked == true)
                        {
                            document.getElementById('keyword-' + SectionName + '-entry-' + ElementName.toLowerCase()).value = document.getElementById('keyword-' + SectionName + '-' + ElementName.toLowerCase()).value;
                        } else {
                            document.getElementById('keyword-' + SectionName + '-entry-' + ElementName.toLowerCase()).value = '';
                        }
                    }
              </script>

        </head>
        <body>
            <input type="checkbox" name="ufs_split_keywords[]" value="Throw" id="keyword-split-throw" onclick="autofill(this.value, 'split');"> <label for="keyword-split-throw">Throw</label>
            <br>
            <input type="text" name="ufs_split_keywords_entry[]" id="keyword-split-entry-throw" style="width:100px; float: right;" onkeyup="autocheck('throw', 'split');"> 
        </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: Yup this worked perfectly. I didn't understand the difference between OnKeyUp and OnKeyDown. I also added in a OnBlur just in case of a user selecting everything with the mouse and then using the right-click -> Delete option. Either way this works. Thanks.